# need to insert php code in path Get Template Part

Tags: php

```
<?php
get_template_part('template/sliders/<?php echo $template1; ?>', 'home');
?>
```

this `<?php echo $template1; ?>` not work in path string any another way to make it work im use wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error, this should work for you:

```
get_template_part('template/sliders/' . $template1, 'home');
```

Comment: ...or even `get_template_part( "template/sliders/$template1", 'home' );` (note [the difference between `"` and `'`](https://secure.php.net/echo)).